# Alternative contacts app, faster than Google's with 2000 contacts?

Tags: contacts

Google's `Contacts` app is very slow to load when I want to quickly get a friend's phone number.

Is there a quicker/lighter contacts app?
I have found nothing fast enough in the Market.

My dream app:

- Loads the list of ~2000 contacts in less than ~3 seconds.
- No need for picture/details in the main list, just name.
- Can import contacts list from vcard or similar.

Comment: Have you looked in the [Market](http://market.android.com)? Why isn't anything there viable?

Comment: If you're just talking about one or two people, you could always just create a shortcut to their contact information on your home screen.

Comment: @Al: Thanks for the shortcut tip! Unfortunately, I am contacting many different people, so shortcuts won't do in this case.

Comment: @Al: Yes I have looked in the Market, all of the apps I have tried are even slower than Google's, because they all show details, picture, etc in the main list, making it very slow to load.

Comment: You can turn off pictures in the contacts app settings. Also have you tried the search widget. You can use it to get a contact without having to open the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will recommend [Dialer One](https://market.android.com/details?id=kz.mek.DialerOne&hl=en). I am 99% sure it can show contacts without pictures. It has lots of customization options, t9 search in contacts in slew of different languages. I have 900+ contacts and is really fast, I hope it works that way for 2000 contacts. Be sure to fiddle with the options after giving it a try.

Comment: Dialer One is wonderful indeed. To make it even better, it seems to be Open Source. Developer website is http://code.google.com/p/dialerone but unfortunately that project gives error 403. Anyone knows where to find the source code?